# Python Linux Subprocess.Call

Tags: python-3.x, linux, subprocess

I have a script that running on windows but when I run it in Linux it errors.

I am running a subprocess call to Invoke a python script and also pass A string Variable.|

When I run it it says it says file not found cannot fine pythonfile.py.

Yes the Python file is in the same directory as the activated script.

```
subprocess.run(['python','pythonfile.py',str(parsed_response)],shell = True)
```

Error

```
pythonfile.py: 1: python: not found with shell
```

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'pythonfile.py',  str(parsed_response)])
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telethon/client/updates.py", line 543, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Tel_To_Disc_Bot/forwardgram.py", line 85, in handler
    subprocess.run(['python', 'pythonfile.py', parsed_response])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1845, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add the error you got in the question as text.

Comment: This means it can't find the `python` program in your `$PATH`. Maybe it's called `python3` instead of `python`? How are you running the main script?

Comment: So I start off with the Directory to go to the folder.

Then I start the script as python3 forwardgram.py.

Which starts the first script.

Then when I put my input and it hits the subprocess.call, It hits that error.
The file is in the same folder as I have it working on windows but in linux it seems to be different.

When I set it as subprocess.call(['python3', 'pythonfile.py',  str(parsed_response)]) it just starts it with python3 and version in terminal.

Comment: Remove `shell = True`

Comment: You get the Second error that it shows

Comment: Is there a recommended alternative to this method for python 3.x on linux
Still a beginner in python as all I find is old posts?

Comment: `subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/python', ...])` should work. Running the `which python` command in your shell will tell you the filename of the installed python program. That is what you need instead of just the word `python`. Above, I guessed that it is installed as `/usr/bin/python`, as that is the default

Comment: I tried the subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/python',pythonfile,py)
But it said it could not find '/usr/bin/python' and nothing about python file.
If this is not normal, could it be the python installed or the linux distro itself?
I am using ubuntu but if there a better distro or recommended anything would be good.

Comment: issue solved I think it was missing certain packages